# How to join rows from the same table with different dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am only a beginner in SQL and I am encountering the following problem:

I have a table with a list of SKU orders where each row displays the SKU, DELIVERY DATE, AND ORDER QUANTITY. I want to somehow rearrange the table in a way that the rows contain not only the delivery date for that given quantity, but also the following delivery date that occured in the future.

The table currently looks like that:

```
SKU/  DELIVERY_DATE/ QUANTITY_ORDERED 
1.SKUx       14/3/2020   200
2.SKUx         19/3/2020    400
3.SKUx          27/3/2020   550
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
SKU/  DELIVERY_DATE/ **NEXT_DELIVERY_DATE**/ QUANTITY_ORDERED <br/>
1.SKUx         14/3/2020 **19/3/2020**  200
2.SKUx         19/3/2020  **27/3/2020**  400
3.SKUx          27/3/2020  **NULL** 550
```

Keep in mind, as shown above, that the days between two deliveries vary (5 days between 14/3-19/3 and 8 days between 27/3-19/3) and therefore cannot pick an absolute value to make the column reappear twice e.g

```
SELECT SKU, DELIVERY_DATE,
       DELIVERY_DATE + 5 AS NEXT_DELIVERY_DATE,
       QUANTITY_ORDERED
FROM TABLE1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Gordon Linoff has already given you an answer, which may be the correct one. Something is unclear in your question though. When you say "next delivery date" do you mean "next delivery date, **regardless of SKU**", or do you mean "next delivery date **for the same SKU**"? Gordon assumed "for the same SKU", which makes the most sense; but in your question, the way you asked it, you didn't mention that. Technically speaking, your question would suggest that you are looking for the next delivery date regardless of SKU (which wouldn't be the most logical thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t1.*,
       lead(delivery_date) over (partition by sku order by delivery_date) as next_delivery_date
from table1 t1
```